# Crystal Reports Attachement Filename With Yesterdays Date

Tags: crystal-reports

I've scheduled a report to run in the Crystal Reports CMC and the report creates an excel file and e-mails it to the recipients. I'm currently naming the extension:

```
%SI_NAME%_%SI_STARTTIME%.%EXT%
```

But this is a bit misleading. The report runs early in the morning and displays data from yesterday and earlier. The name might imply to some users that it has today's data and earlier. Is it possible to have SI_STARTTIME - 1 or something along those lines to get yesterdays date as the files name?

Thanks!

Comment: currently how are you naming the crystal report file name?

Comment: %SI_NAME%_%SI_STARTTIME%.%EXT%

Comment: are you doing any batch file scheduling?

Comment: Nope, just scheduled it in the CMC

Comment: Have you got any answer for it?
I am also facing the same issue.